# Unable to boot Ubuntu 12.04 installer on USB Pendrive created with Universal USB Installer.

Tags: 12.04, installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using an HP Pendrive. I made the Pendrive bootable with the Universal USB Installer v1.8.9.7.

I was not able to boot  from the Pendrive. Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Would you please provide more information about what happens when you attempt to boot from your Pendrive? What file system is your Pendrive formatted with? FAT32? Or something else? If you view your Pendrive in Windows Explorer is it similar to [**this screenshot**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MA99D.png)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why it doesn't work for you. But this one works simple UI. Easy to use http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The same here. Universal USB installer 1-9-1-6 didn't work for Ubuntu 12.04 server. I suspect it doesn't create "isolinux" properly. Unetbootin works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following to solve your problem:

1. Format the USB Drive to FAT32
2. Run Univeral USB Installer 1.8.9.7 as "Administrator"

I have had a problem where the boot MBR would not be written/created as a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

Download and run `unetbootin.exe` from [**this link**](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Then follow the steps shown in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of unetbootin window annotated with steps to perform]

When UNetbootin processing completes, reboot your PC and change the BIOS Setting for the first boot device to "USB DRIVE".

Reboot again. You should now be able to run the Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a USB 3 thumb drive and USB 3 port?  I can't boot my laptop with a USB 3 drive in a USB 3 port but if I use a USB 2 drive it's fine.  It seems that there are a lot of (hardwware firmware) problems with USB 3 right now.  For some people a BIOS update will fix it, didn't for me though.