# Ubuntu 12.04 installer not booting from usb

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb, unetbootin

okay so this is what i did so far...

downloaded ubuntu 12.04 LTS from ubunutu website.

downloaded UNetbootin from http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

did exactly this [Unable to boot Ubuntu 12.04 installer on USB Pendrive created with Universal USB Installer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142283/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-12-04-installer-on-usb-pendrive-created-with-universal-usb)

tried running UNetbootin as administrator too but still won't boot.

my laptop is HP pavilion G6 core i5 3rd gen. OS is windows 7 32-bit.

i don't know if this is anyhow related to this issue. i tried installing ubuntu(old version that i had written to a CD 2 years back). i booted successfully from CD but the installation was stuck in ubuntu loading screen. so i had to use the power button in my laptop to turnoff the machine and start again. didn't try that again and since the CD didn't work i decided to download a fresh copy(ubuntu 12.04 LTS) from website. so... now i am trying to install from usb  because i am too lazy to go out and buy some blank DVDs :|

note: i have never installed or tried ubuntu before. so i am not sure what else i should do in this type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we keep getting such reports of problems with Windows USB bootable disk creators.

**Instead of UNetBootIn**, you can perhaps try **Universal USB Installer** here: [www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)